# "Buzzing" vs "buzzing noise."

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage

What's the difference between the two?

Example sentences:

> *Bzzz, bzzz.* What was that buzzing?
>
> *Bzzz, bzzz.* What was that buzzing noise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Buzz" is the [onomatopoetic](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/onomatopoeia) way to describe that particular kind of noise.  "Buzzing noise" is therefore *redundant* -- but still used, in the way people say things like "ATM machine" or "postpone until later" or "regular routine".

Comment: and PIN number.